# Query still costs us even when the source is empty

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a question about my query, I make a query which has one source that is scheduled and this source is sometimes empty. Yet, when it's empty it still costs us some amount of money.

The query would be like this, with the scheduled_source_a is sometimes an empty table (scheduled - truncate)

```
WITH scheduled_source_a AS

(SELECT *
FROM project.dataset.abc),

source_b AS

(SELECT
      date_key,
      search_id
FROM project.dataset_def)

-- Final Query

SELECT *
FROM source_b
WHERE date_key BETWEEN (SELECT (start_date) FROM table) AND (SELECT (end_date) FROM table)
```

Is there any workaround so that when the source is empty my final query doesn't cost us at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bill you see should be the 10MB minimum charge regardless of how small a table is.

You may use scripting plus metatable to avoid a query if table is empty:

```sql
declare isEmpty default (select row_count > 0 from yourDataset.__TABLES__ where <table_name_filter>);
IF isEmpty 
  THEN <do somthing>
END IF;
```